# Is it possible to clone jquery DOM object with props?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to next behavior:

- create DOM object via jQuery `$("<div>")`
- assign prop to it `var domObj = $("<div>").prop("foo", "bar");`
- clone created object `var clonedDomObj = domObj.clone(true);`
- read prop from cloned object `clonedDomObj.prop("foo")`
  see code pen [example](http://codepen.io/mikhail_vasilchenko/pen/bprpoL)

The problem is, when I read `.prop("foo")` from `clonedDomObj` I receive `undefined`

The question is: Is it possible somehow to clone jQuery DOM object with props?

Comment: try with `clone(true,true);`

Comment: by default second parameter takes value of first, see https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: @Mikhail I updated my answer , I think the updated version would be more helpful to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> objects and arrays within element data are not copied and will
>   continue to be shared between the cloned element and the original
>   element. To deep copy all data, **copy each one manually**:

```js
var domObj = $("<div class='text'>").prop("foo", "bar");
$("#p1").text(domObj.prop("foo"));

var clonedDomObj = domObj.clone(true).prop("foo",domObj.prop("foo"));
$("#p2").text(clonedDomObj.prop("foo"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Original Value: </span><span id="p1"></span>
<br/>
<span>Cloned Value:   </span><span id="p2"></span>
```

> As of jQuery 1.4, all element data (attached by the .data() method) is also copied to the new copy.

```js
var domObj = $("<div class='text'>").data("foo", "bar");
$("#p1").text(domObj.data("foo"));
var clonedDomObj = domObj.clone(true);
$("#p2").text(clonedDomObj.data("foo"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Original Value: </span><span id="p1"></span>
<br/>
<span>Cloned Value:   </span><span id="p2"></span>
```

Comment: The data() approach is exactly what I'm looking for

Answer (score 1):

This is the only way I found.

```js
   var domObj = $("<div>").prop("foo", "bar");
    $("#p1").text(domObj.prop("foo"));
    
    var clonedDomObj = $("#p1").clone(true);
    $("#p2").text(clonedDomObj.html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Original Value: </span><span id="p1"></span>
<br/>
<span>Cloned Value:   </span><span id="p2"></span>
```